# Как передавать токены с сервера авторизации?

Tags: веб-программирование

Пытаюсь написать сервер авторизации, который может выдавать access, refresh, id токены другим сервисам по запросу или редиректу пользователя на login страницу.

Если я правильно понимаю схему то она такая:

1. Клиент пытается авторизоваться на сайте А, нажав кнопку авторизации через сервер авторизации сервиса Б.
2. Сервис А редиректит пользователя на endpoint сервера авторизациис сервиса Б, который умеет показыавть форму логин/пароль. Допустим, запрос на этот эндпоинт выглят так: `https://service-b/authorization/login?requested-service=domain-of-service-b.ru`.
3. Пользователь вводит в форму логин/пароль, нажимает Log in
4. Сервер авторизации проверяет введенную пару логин/пароль и если все ок, то выдает генерит токены для пользователя.
5. Далее нужно как то передать эти токены `domain-of-service-b.ru`

Вот здесь я не могу найти решение лучше, чем установить куку в браузере клиента для домена domain-of-service-b.ru. Ибо я не понимаю, как мне передать токены domain-of-service-b.ru. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это делается в реальных системах?

Comment: Зачем писать свой сервер? [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) отличное решение.

Comment: Так же есть отличная площадка  [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://www.oauth.com/playground/), которая демонстрирует работу различных потоков авторизации, на случай, если будете писать своё решение.